# AT command sent to modem from microcontroller is ignored

Tags: uart, msp430

Please help, I spent hours trying to rootcause the problem.

Setup: MSP430 (F5529 microcontroller), HW UART (USCI_A0) and modem connected (uBlox Leon G100). I am sure the USCI_A0 port works well because if I connect it via USB-to-RS232 to the PC I can see the correct traffic.

A simple

```
uart_puts(UART_MODEM, "AT+CPWROFF\r");
```

shall put AT+CPWROFF to the modem. And it probably does but modem does not power off. If I simply connect modem to PC and type "AT+CPWROFF" finished by Enter then the modem powers off.
I also confirmed on the PC console that the "\r" works well - it just returns the carriage, correctly. Tried "\n\r", does not work either. Checked in the modem settings for S3 character and it's 013 (CR or \r).

I have no idea what is wrong. PC-to-modem works well (I can power off the modem), MSP430-to-PC works ok (I can see that the microconroller really puts AT+CPWROFF\r on the UART), but MSP430-to-modem does not work.

I can determine if the modem is turned on or off by looking at the current consumed.

Please, any hints?

Comment: Do other commands sent from the microcontroller to the modem work?

Comment: @EricJ.No, and I connected logic analyzer to see what is going wrong on the UART. This is the dump of the correct communication being made on the /dev/ttyUSB0 to modem via Python script: http://inet24.pl/~morales/modem_ok.html and this is the communication done by the microcontroller (the same settings): http://inet24.pl/~morales/modem_nook.html. It seems the modem responds with rubbish, also there is a FRAME data present which is variable in time of occurrance (sometimes I have even 20 FRAMEs). I used both 115200 and 9600 baudrates to exclude clock inaccuracy. I'm getting insane...

Answer (score 0):

OK, issue solved. If you take a look at the detected baudrate on the links I sent, you will notice that with PC the exact baudrate was 9585 (which is 0.14% of sync difference) while with the MCU it is 7862 (which is 2.73% of sync difference). I switched to 4MHz crystal and now have approx 0.23% out of sync. It's really wondering that the DCO gives so unstable clock.